# How to convert object[] to a more specifically typed array

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, casting

This would be pretty straight forward if I knew the types at compile time or if it was a generic parameter, because I could do something like `myArray.Cast<T>()` But what I actually have is essentially this.  I do not have a known type or generic parameter.  I have a `System.Type` variable.

```
// could actually be anything else
Type myType = typeof(string);  

// i already know all the elements are the correct types
object[] myArray = new object[] { "foo", "bar" };
```

Is there some kind of reflection magic I can do to get a `string[]` reference containing the same data? (where `string` isn't known at compile time)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you know the type only at runtime, you would have to have that reference as some more general type anyway.

Comment: I am trying to assign the array to a property on an object that I am constructing using reflection.  The end use of this is an object mapper that can translate between different class hierarchies that are identical, but in different namespaces.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's not really a cast as such (I'm allocating a new array and copying the original), but maybe this can help you out?

```
Type myType = typeof(string);
object[] myArray = new object[] { "foo", "bar" };

Array destinationArray = Array.CreateInstance(myType, myArray.Length);
Array.Copy(myArray, destinationArray, myArray.Length);
```

In this code, `destinationArray` will be an instance of `string[]` (or an array of whatever type `myType` was).

Comment: I know I was asking for a cast in the original question, but this is basically exactly what I actually wanted.  `Array.CreatInstance()` was the part I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a one liner but it can be done with two lines. Given your specified `Array` of elements of the correct type `myArray` and the specified `Type` parameter `myType`, dynamically calling `.Cast<"myType">.ToArray()` would work.

```
var typeConvertedEnumerable = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
    .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { myType })
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { myArray });
var typeConvertedArray = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
    .GetMethod("ToArray", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { myType })
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { typeConvertedEnumerable });
```

While the method generation is slower than a direct call, it is O(1) on the size of the array. The benefit of this approach is, if `IEnumerable<"myType">` would be acceptable, the second line is not needed, and therefore I do not believe the array will be copied.

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform such a cast, because the arrays object[] and string[] are actually different types and are not convertible.  However, if you wanted to pass different such types to a function, just make the parameter IEnumerable.  You can then pass an array of any type, list of any type, etc.

```
    // Make an array from any IEnumerable (array, list, etc.)
    Array MakeArray(IEnumerable parm, Type t)
    {
        if (parm == null)
            return Array.CreateInstance(t, 0);
        int arrCount;
        if (parm is IList)     // Most arrays etc. implement IList
            arrCount = ((IList)parm).Count;
        else
        {
            arrCount = 0;
            foreach (object nextMember in parm)
            {
                if (nextMember.GetType() == t)
                    ++arrCount;
            }
        }
        Array retval = Array.CreateInstance(t, arrCount);
        int ix = 0;
        foreach (object nextMember in parm)
        {
            if (nextMember.GetType() == t)
                retval.SetValue(nextMember, ix);
            ++ix;
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: `IEnumerable` will not work for me, because I need to assign the array reference to a property via reflection.

Comment: You could use the same MyFunc above to return a string array too -- from any kind of object (if it isn't string, call ToString on it).

Comment: OK, I changed my function to crawl any IEnumerable to make a string array from it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  `string` was just an example I used to illustrate the problem.  I need code that will work for any type.  My code may or may not actually be handling strings.  I don't know that during compile time.

Comment: OK, give me a couple of minutes, I'll make it more generic.

Comment: I've now made it so it creates the array from a given type for any IEnumerable (array, list, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to manually go through every object, get the most generic common type between them, and then create a new array of that type and copy the elements. There's no one-liner for this.

Comment: The actual object references are already correct.  It's just that they're contained in an `object[]`.  I just need to copy the same references to a new array.

Comment: @recursive: If by "correct" you mean that they're the same, then just get the type of the first object and treat it as the most common type. Then create a new array of that type and copy over the objects.

Answer (score 1):

This will create the array that you want, but I don't know what you're going to do with it afterwards, since the compiler still doesn't know what the type of the array object is.

```
Type myType = typeof(string);
object[] myArray = new object[] { "foo", "bar" };

Array myArrayOfTheCorrectType = Array.CreateInstance(myType, myArray.Length);
for (int index = 0; index < myArray.Length; index++)
    myArrayOfTheCorrectType.SetValue(myArray[index], index);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is it cant be cast.  I know alot of other people have offered solutions, but the answer is no.  I think the reason is because the type of the array is object, which is lower than string.  The compiler will not let the upconversion happen unless you do it manually.  I also played around with the DLR stuff, but it still types it as object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // could actually be anything else
        Type myType = typeof(string);
        Type myArrayType = Array.CreateInstance(myType, 1).GetType();

        // i already know all the elements are the correct types
        object[] myArray = new object[] { "foo", "bar" };

        MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(myArrayType);
        object castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { myArray });
    }

    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
}
```